# How to change the dataset format on Huggingface

Tags: python, huggingface-datasets

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
rowid,url,text,domain_id,domain_id_label,width,height,similarity,punsafe,pwatermark,aesthetic,hash,__index_level_0__
1,https://cdn.idahopotato.com/cache/4075b86c99bc2c46f927f3be5949d161_w310.jpg,Fattoush Salad with Roasted Potatoes,1,cdn.idahopotato.com,310,206,0.32190072536468506,1.9172496e-05,0.042544544,6.0983996,-7769833748550554891,113
2,https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Gw5LBM0zYU8/TX46gXdbI2I/AAAAAAAABto/MI-8zA_yR84/s1600/24430-virginia_woolf.jpg,"an analysis of self portrayal in novels by virginia woolf A room of one's own study guide contains a biography of virginia woolf, literature essays, quiz questions, major themes, characters, and a full summary and analysis about a room of one's own a room of one's own summary.",2,lh3.googleusercontent.com,720,1000,0.33762750029563904,1.737107e-06,0.40568027,6.109017,8675719636262469033,877
3,https://www.mediaplaynews.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/last-christmas.png,Christmas Comes Early to U.K. Weekly Home Entertainment Chart,3,www.mediaplaynews.com,900,601,0.33475491404533386,0.023501933,0.4089923,6.0230927,-510709293545570516,952
4,https://statesofincarceration.org/sites/default/files/Amy_Tyson-Dorothea_Lynde_Dix_c1850-55.jpg,Amy Garcia Wikipedia a legacy of reform: dorothea dix (1802–1887) | states of,4,statesofincarceration.org,840,1112,0.332019180059433,5.6428403e-06,0.15564087,6.431951,7982521258241828259,1163
5,https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0094/8653/2687/products/FAM-1202ZT_300x300.jpg?v=1570195462,3D Metal Cornish Harbour Painting,5,cdn.shopify.com,300,300,0.32057473063468933,8.072326e-06,0.10981648,6.1677094,-2541341491343729392,1431
6,http://l.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/DVaATazcS6Jq8DuG8pWqVA--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTc1NztweW9mZj0wO3E9NzU7c209MTt3PTk2MA--/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/ap_webfeeds/82c71bbdef270916370f6a7067000065.jpg,"""In this undated photo provided by the New York City Ballet, Robert Fairchild performs in """"In Creases"""" by choreographer Justin Peck which is being performed by the New York City Ballet in New York. (AP Photo/New York City Ballet, Paul Kolnik)""",6,l.yimg.com,960,757,0.3140464425086975,0.00040382147,0.44375956,6.0047417,1037540669530061759,1506
7,https://render.fineartamerica.com/images/rendered/search/flat/round-beach-towel/images/artworkimages/medium/1/winter-wonderland-anne-gifford.jpg?&targetx=0&targety=-159&imagewidth=788&imageheight=1106&modelwidth=788&modelheight=788&backgroundcolor=E5E9ED&orientation=0&removethiseventually=true,Round Beach Towel featuring the painting Winter Wonderland by Anne Gifford,7,render.fineartamerica.com,180,180,0.3693836927413941,1.1998264e-07,0.29982352,6.015644,-2125211670902297681,2101
8,https://en-fmgdesigns.s3.amazonaws.com/53366.jpg?v%5Cx3d9543cd464bebc77aef550c7740b87027%0D%0A,"sun, rays, Spring, Mountains - Beautiful views wallpapers: 2560x1440",8,en-fmgdesigns.s3.amazonaws.com,541,360,0.30625030398368835,7.164156e-06,0.16085383,6.0956593,-8492675886823456363,2397
9,"https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/1e3ad9ba-d3bb-4750-9318-aa0d1a7f50b0/d6s1yej-9bf6e835-4d10-4708-a7c1-32143aae41f5.jpg/v1/fill/w_177,h_250,q_70,strp/sailor_moon_by_charlie_bowater_d6s1yej-250t.jpg?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7ImhlaWdodCI6Ijw9ODc3IiwicGF0aCI6IlwvZlwvMWUzYWQ5YmEtZDNiYi00NzUwLTkzMTgtYWEwZDFhN2Y1MGIwXC9kNnMxeWVqLTliZjZlODM1LTRkMTAtNDcwOC1hN2MxLTMyMTQzYWFlNDFmNS5qcGciLCJ3aWR0aCI6Ijw9NjIwIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmltYWdlLm9wZXJhdGlvbnMiXX0.I2GILU7wflVd1QXJ0TQRzn4a0jqx_WHnhz1oDWfIR0I",Sailor Moon by Charlie-Bowater,9,images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com,177,250,0.35163620114326477,0.0015848279,0.23917364,6.1056666,7304372338209907934,2400
10,https://konachan.com/data/preview/7c/42/7c42a9164bcfb0fce7c88085f09d9dce.jpg,Rating: Safe Score: 171 Tags: aeolian_(wlop) black_hair braids building butterfly city clouds ghostblade headdress landscape logo long_hair ponytail scenic skirt sky sunset watermark wlop User: luckyluna,10,konachan.com,300,166,0.3197726607322693,0.052469403,0.22856134,6.2950845,2908580222882266365,2704
11,https://render.fineartamerica.com/images/rendered/search/print/images-medium-5/1-lake-in-winter-crater-lake-crater-panoramic-images.jpg,"Lake In Winter, Crater Lake, Crater Art Print",7,render.fineartamerica.com,400,266,0.318795382976532,1.3206559e-06,1.0,6.085382,-8877775580192596443,2988
12,https://dreamlandtours.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/IMG_1768-scaled.jpg,Hiker gazes at the Wave with reflection pool,11,dreamlandtours.net,1920,2560,0.2865600287914276,4.9344366e-05,0.10647261,6.072795,-1859498664806039492,3017
13,https://t2.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/53/11/83/400_F_53118382_iVHtfP2XJVZVULdvRulnZlBXctv3mtbK.jpg,beautiful blond woman with flowers of apple tree,12,t2.ftcdn.net,500,334,0.3716212213039398,0.9306521,0.1296275,6.0769506,-1891859739494487481,3148
14,https://i2.wp.com/voxdominus.ru/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/UK_Arpen_6_Seat_Dining_Table-1.jpg?resize=750%2C500&ssl=1,table,13,i2.wp.com,750,500,0.2828073501586914,0.00011419203,0.08425643,6.151825,4236973487256703435,3263
15,http://render.fineartamerica.com/images/rendered/medium/greeting-card/images-medium-5/intense-siamese-cat-painting-print-2-svetlana-novikova.jpg,Giclee Prints Greeting Cards - Intense Siamese Cat painting print 2 Greeting Card by Svetlana Novikova,7,render.fineartamerica.com,646,470,0.3692695200443268,7.591725e-07,0.07571758,6.105506,-7442211688250030372,3353
16,https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/image-photo/stock-photo-bruges-beautiful-scenic-cityscape-with-a-medieval-groenerei-canal-reflections-canal-boat-tour-450w-385227766.jpg,"Bruges, Beautiful Scenic cityscape with a medieval Groenerei canal reflections, canal boat tour embankment jetty and the quay Dijver and Illuminated Church of Our Lady at night in summer, Belgium - stock photo",14,thumb9.shutterstock.com,338,470,0.35601797699928284,0.001455605,0.40309513,6.3248205,2854978087673303320,3546
17,https://s.yimg.com/ny/api/res/1.2/oWf.pIWNf51jf0LXqcZTwA--/YXBwaWQ9aGlnaGxhbmRlcjtzbT0xO3c9MTA1NDtoPTcwMDtpbD1wbGFuZQ--/http://media.zenfs.com/en_US/Sports/AP_General/201405211411510869115-p5.jpg,"President Barack Obama waves to members of the NFL Super Bowl champion Seattle Seahawks football team after welcoming the team to the East Room of the White House in Washington, Wednesday, May 21, 2014. The Seahawks defeated the Denver Broncos in Super Bowl XLVIII. (AP Photo/Susan Walsh)",15,s.yimg.com,1054,700,0.31588438153266907,0.0033192635,0.08139456,6.063474,-5848983857644015815,3611
18,http://render.fineartamerica.com/images/rendered/medium/greeting-card/images-medium-5/family-stroll-phil-jaeger.jpg,African Elephants Greeting Cards - Family Stroll Greeting Card by Phil Jaeger,7,render.fineartamerica.com,455,646,0.3647528290748596,4.121351e-05,0.10197897,6.1357856,-1235949504306333001,3627
19,https://us.123rf.com/450wm/massonforstock/massonforstock1409/massonforstock140900046/31356863-lonely-girl-with-suitcase-at-near-airplane-photo-in-old-image-style.jpg,Lonely girl with suitcase at near airplane. Photo in old image style. photo,16,us.123rf.com,300,450,0.32632535696029663,0.40212536,0.13383819,6.2053504,3222426229479515080,3655
20,https://www.artbrokerage.com/artthumb/roulette_73713_1/360x322/Leon_Roulette_Harborside_At_Portofino_2010_Embellished.jpg,Harborside At Portofino 2010 Embellished Limited Edition Print - Leon Roulette,17,www.artbrokerage.com,360,270,0.3299652934074402,2.903781e-05,0.076089926,6.554896,-7726527588692324976,3675
21,https://gerrymiles.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Underwater-painting-spadefish-gerry-miles.jpg,Underwater painting of spadefish Spade fishes above a shipwreck by Gerry Miles,18,gerrymiles.nl,1300,1166,0.3595767021179199,2.9819766e-06,0.19193313,6.123009,978872985244231604,3799
22,https://us.123rf.com/450wm/lanabrest/lanabrest1511/lanabrest151100017/47935708-a-fantasy-about-drem-island-with-a-castle-on-it-original-oil-painting-uncharted.jpg?ver=6,cliff: A fantasy about drem island with a castle on it. Original oil painting Uncharted,16,us.123rf.com,450,300,0.3242622911930084,8.0927486e-05,0.22578254,6.2720966,-1996111269057685352,4161
23,https://us.123rf.com/450wm/lightwise/lightwise1512/lightwise151200042/49949750-help-concept-and-corporate-support-as-a-group-of-people-excluded-from-advancing-on-a-drawing-of-a-li.jpg?ver=6,business education: Help concept and corporate support as a group of people excluded from advancing on a drawing of a line that is being erased and sketched by a pencil. Stock Photo,16,us.123rf.com,450,341,0.3243783414363861,0.00043466687,0.6340423,6.0079627,-7188812172422378228,4537
24,https://t2.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/75/71/11/240_F_75711179_golOjcINgc5vbCXyj23AmeaqVcvKp2NM.jpg,close-up portrait of woman in black paint and green leaf on face,12,t2.ftcdn.net,479,240,0.3160702586174011,0.013185352,0.20235766,6.023582,-920255550450707673,4539
25,https://naglly.com/archives/2016/10/04/Mont_Saint_Michel_from_a_drone.png,Mont_Saint_Michel_from_a_drone.png,19,naglly.com,500,229,0.36000365018844604,5.2968724e-05,0.168854,6.2057323,8488573082681257870,4669
26,https://i.imgur.com/ajb54XYm.jpg,burning_planet_by_parad1gm.png,20,i.imgur.com,320,320,0.30053475499153137,0.00073572993,0.004659973,6.1471276,215317020151320997,5501
...
```

This dataset is already on Huggingface: https://huggingface.co/datasets/oo92/diffusion-dataset/viewer/oo92--diffusion-dataset/train

The `url` column are the urls of the images that correspond to the `text` column entries.

I am trying to get this dataset to the same format as Pokemon BLIP[image]

I already have all of the images downloaded in a separate folder but I couldn't figure out how to upload the data on huggingface in this format.

This is how I'm trying to use it:

[image]

Where, instead of the Pokemon, its the first image and text from my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am answering you quite late, but here is the easiest solution to achieve the same result as the dataset pokemon-blip-capcion. You can also see the implementation in the standard documentation [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/image_dataset)

For my dataset, I created metadata.jsonl file when i write string {"image":"2022.jpg", "text": "neon skull"}.
You can add more information if you wish. Next, you need to place this file in the folder with your data and use the standard functions of the diffusers library to load the dataset and push to hub
[image: my folder with data]
[image: code]